# Right way to use windows XAML host control in Winforms project?

Tags: c#, winforms, xaml, xaml-islands

Goal: I have a winforms project and I wish to use XAML controls in the UI. I plan to do this using Xaml islands

I have imported the following nuget package Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.XamlHost version 5.1.0(saw that version 6 > onwards had issues and folks reverted to 5.1.0). I tried to add the Xaml Host control in the Winforms designer but when I create an object of the Form , the UI crashes.

I tried using the XAML host control in the code behind instead but that results into a crash as well

My code behind looks like this

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
{
  public TestForm()
  {
    this.InitializeComponent();
  }

  public void ShowUI()
  {
    WindowsXamlHost windowsXamlHost = new WindowsXamlHost();
    this.Controls.Add(windowsXamlHost);

    Button testButton = new Button();
    testButton.Content = "Test";
           
    windowsXamlHost.Child = testButton;
    this.Show();
    this.BringToFront();
  }
}
```

I added the following to the app.manifest

```
<maxversiontested Id="10.0.18295.0"/>
<supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />
```

In main.cs

```
TestForm test = new TestForm();
test.ShowUI();
```

The UI crashes each time.
Can I get help understanding:

1. Why the UI crashes?
2. Is the way to use XAML Host control incorrect ?

Comment: Your debugger will tell you why it crashes - have you used your debugger? If not, why not?

Comment: `Button testButton = new Button();` <-- Are you certain this is a XAML/WPF/UWP/Etc `Button` and not a WinForms `System.Windows.Forms.Button`?

Comment: The debugger tells me its an unhandled Win32 exception but not where the exception happens and why. My UWP app launches a full trust launch process which launches this win forms UI. So the exception happens in the full trust process and the the debugger doesn't show me the location of the exception. I have also tried to attach the debugger to the full trust process but the process gets terminated too quickly to get anything meaningful

Comment: Adding exceptions that I get  Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFCDBD82C90 (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) in A.exe  : 0xC000027B: An application-internal exception has occurred (parameters: 0x0000022E7553B0C0, 0x0000000000000003).
 
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFCF55CDDAF (combase.dll) in A.exe: 0xC0000602:  A fail fast exception occurred. Exception handlers will not be invoked and the process will be terminated immediately

Comment: Please post your **actual** `app.manifest` because (from your post), `<maxversiontested Id="10.0.18295.0"/>` is not a valid element: `maxVersionTested` is an attribute.

Comment: Also post your **full** entrypoint `class` - are you using `[STAThread]`? Do you have any static initializers running before your entrypoint?